# Guava EventBus: don't catch RuntimeException

Tags: java, exception, guava, runtimeexception

I use guava's EventBus, unfortunately it catches and logs the InvocationTargetException that occurs when an event-handler throws a RuntimeException. Can i disable this behaviour?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As it stands, this is a deliberate decision, and discussed in the EventBus docs:

> Handlers should not, in general, throw. If they do, the EventBus will catch and log the exception. This is rarely the right solution for error handling and should not be relied upon; it is intended solely to help find problems during development.

Alternative solutions are [being considered](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=766), though I seriously doubt they'll make it into release 12.

Answer (score 4):

Here is code for lazy

```
public class Events
{
    public static EventBus createWithExceptionDispatch()
    {
        final EventBus bus;

        MySubscriberExceptionHandler exceptionHandler = new MySubscriberExceptionHandler();
        bus = new EventBus(exceptionHandler);
        exceptionHandler.setBus(bus);
        return bus;
    }

    private static class MySubscriberExceptionHandler implements SubscriberExceptionHandler
    {
        @Setter
        EventBus bus;

        @Override
        public void handleException(Throwable exception, SubscriberExceptionContext context)
        {
            ExceptionEvent event = new ExceptionEvent(exception, context);
            bus.post(event);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, you can subscribe `ExceptionEvent`.

Here is my `ExceptionEvent` for just copy&paste

```
@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
public class ExceptionEvent
{
    private final Throwable exception;
    private final SubscriberExceptionContext context;
    private final Object extra;

    public ExceptionEvent(Throwable exception)
    {
        this(exception, null);
    }

    public ExceptionEvent(Throwable exception, Object extra)
    {
        this(exception,null,extra);
    }

    public ExceptionEvent(Throwable exception, SubscriberExceptionContext context)
    {
        this(exception,context,null);
    }

    public ExceptionEvent(Throwable exception, SubscriberExceptionContext context, Object extra)
    {
        this.exception = exception;
        this.context = context;
        this.extra = extra;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just inherit guava EventBus, and write you own custom eventbus.
Tips: This class should write in com.google.common.eventbus package, so that internal method can be overwrite.

```
package com.google.common.eventbus;

import com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors;

public class CustomEventBus extends EventBus {

    /**
     * Creates a new EventBus with the given {@code identifier}.
     *
     * @param identifier a brief name for this bus, for logging purposes. Should be a valid Java
     *     identifier.
     */
    public CustomEventBus(String identifier) {
        super(
            identifier,
            MoreExecutors.directExecutor(),
            Dispatcher.perThreadDispatchQueue(),
            LoggingHandler.INSTANCE);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new EventBus with the given {@link SubscriberExceptionHandler}.
     *
     * @param exceptionHandler Handler for subscriber exceptions.
     * @since 16.0
     */
    public CustomEventBus(SubscriberExceptionHandler exceptionHandler) {
        super(
            "default",
            MoreExecutors.directExecutor(),
            Dispatcher.perThreadDispatchQueue(),
            exceptionHandler);
    }

    @Override
    void handleSubscriberException(Throwable e, SubscriberExceptionContext context) {
        throw new EventHandleException(e);
    }
}
```